# What's the point of assassins taking over a city?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I'm looking at a <s>minion</s> assassin mission in Assassin's Creed: Revelations and it says the rewards is that

> The Assassins will take control of this city.

Does that have any tangible benefits?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By taking over a city, you're effectively creating another source of income and supplies.  Just like when you take over **Templar Dens** and renovate the stores in the zone.  The difference here is that you acquire the different revenue/item generating sources through the different missions.

Once you have removed the templar influence in the city, you should send assassins to the missions that show the difficulty bar as stars (rather than diamonds).  Being successful in that mission will increase the assassin influence in the city as well as other perks such as additional income, experience for the assassins that are occupying the city, crafting items and an additional slot for occupation.

Comment: You can get up to five assassins occupying a city.  I would also just add that it's HUGELY profitable to max out your income from other cities, way more than just focusing on Constantinople would be otherwise.