# What is templar control?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

Some of the assassin missions in Assassin's Creed:Revelations offer "-X% Templar Control".

What does this mean? What is templar control and why do I want to keep it low?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lower the templar control is, the easier it is to seize the city.

See here for what it does [What's the point of assassins taking over a city?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39473/whats-the-point-of-assassins-taking-over-a-city)